# getRelevantGoogleReviews is not a function error in wordpress but works in Localhost

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps places Javascrip library in my site, to retrieve my Store's reviews & ratings, I tested it in localhost, everything works fine, but when I use the code in my wordpress site, I get a error saying *getRelevantGoogleReviews is not a function* I even tried to setTimeout for 3 seconds for my site to fetch the reviews, but it does not work. Any idea why?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="reviews__content" id="reviews__content">
    </ul>
    <div id="service-helper"></div>


    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=getRelevantGoogleReviews">
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.getRelevantGoogleReviews = function() {
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService($('#service-helper').get(0)); // note that it removes the content inside div with tag '#service-helper'

        service.getDetails({
            placeId: 'ChIJ0YnbDpIUrjsRUiJwpVPcmDk' // get a placeId using https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-id
        }, function(place, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                var resultcontent = '';
                for (i = 0; i < place.reviews.length; ++i) {
                    if (place.reviews[i].rating >= 4) {
                        //window.alert('Name:' + place.name + '. ID: ' + place.place_id + '. address: ' + place.formatted_address);
                        resultcontent += '<li class="reviews__item">'
                        resultcontent += '<div class="reviews__review-er">' + place.reviews[i].author_name + '</div>';
                        var reviewDate = new Date(place.reviews[i].time * 1000);
                        resultcontent += '<div class="reviews__review-er"> <p>Rating: ' + place.reviews[i].rating; + ' </p></div>';
                        var reviewDateMM = reviewDate.getMonth() + 1;
                        var reviewDateFormatted = reviewDate.getDate() + '/' + reviewDateMM + '/' + reviewDate.getFullYear();
                        resultcontent += '<div class="reviews__review-date">' + reviewDateFormatted + '</div>';
                        resultcontent += '<div class="reviews__review-rating reviews__review-rating--' + place.reviews[i].rating + '"></div>';
                        if (!!place.reviews[i].text) {
                            resultcontent += '<div class="reviews__review-comment">' + place.reviews[i].text + '</div>';
                            resultcontent += '<div class="reviews__review-comment"> <a target="_blank" href="'+place.reviews[i].author_url+'">click here</a></div>';
                        }
                        resultcontent += '</li>'
                    }

                }
                $('#reviews__content').append("<b>Corporate Office</b><br><br>" + resultcontent);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look like they JS interpreter haven't had enough time to declare the function. Here's what you can do about it:

Swap google library and your JS code so that your code is declared above the lib.

```
<script>//your code</script>
<script async defer src="...google..lib" />
```

Here's your code working on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z3e07rep/1/)